# Use Action instead of Func

Tags: c#, cross-platform, action, abstraction, func

This is from the factory pattern, where a property is used to get an instance via `Create`:

```
public class Dialer
{
    public static Func<Dialer> Create;
    public bool MakeCall(string number) ...
    public Dialer(IDialer impl) { ... }
}
```

Then a lambda expression is assigned to the property delegate in the platform-specific project with

```
Dialer.Create = () => new Dialer(new PhoneDialeriOS());
```

and to get an instance in the platform-independent project I use

```
this.dialer = Dialer.Create();
```

Now I'm looking to use

```
public static Action<Dialer> Create;
```

If I get this right, the assignment now is

```
Dialer.Create = (d) => new Dialer(new PhoneDialeriOS());
```

but how do I get an instance?

```
this.dialer = // ?
```

By using `this.dialer = Dialer.Create();` I get

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'obj' of 'Action'

But it doesn't make sense to pass an instance of `PhoneDialeriOS` here, because there is no access to it in the platform-independent code. I think the example I'm regarding to is misleading or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Action<Dialer>` is a a delegate that *receives* a `Dialer` instance, and returns `void`. It's an `Action`, after all. If you want it to return a value (and get an argument), you need to use `Func<Dialer, Dialer>` instead.

Comment: That's the thing. The example talks about `public static Action<Dialer> Create;`, but that is not possible because I can't pass the instance. Imho the example is false. `public static Action<Dialer> Create;` is the only correct way.

Comment: `public static Action<Dialer> Create` is still a delegate that doesn't return anything. I'm not sure how you can consider a factory that cannot produce anything as "the only correct way".

Comment: You are right. I made a copy & paste error. `public static Func<Dialer> Create;` is the only correct way.

Comment: @testing It's not the *only* correct way.  It's the most typical and sensible way.  There's always another way.

Comment: @Servy: You will be right. But I don't see an option using `Action` here. Or do you? I don't know what the author had in mind with this. Perhaps there is some fancy architectural construct behind ...

Answer (score 1):

The following could be possible usages

```
var specific_dialer = new Dialer(new PhoneDialeriOS());
var defualt_dialer = Dialer.Create();
```

**Edit**

Of course you can do something like

```
Dialer.Create = () => new Dialer(new PhoneDialerAndroid());
```

without the (likely a wrong copy/paste) line with the Action

Comment: Ahh I see. The thing is that the access to the specific dialer is very limited (only in the platform-specific project).